# CATransform3D no perspective

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform, catransform3d

I have done this before but I somehow don't get this to work. I have googled a bit but none of the answers I have found solve it.

I am just trying to add a small view to my `self.view` and would like to rotate this added subview on its y-axis with perspective.

Here is the code:

```
UIView *rotatingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){{40.0f, 50.0f}, 50.0f, 50.0f}];
rotatingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -500.0;

transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(20.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
rotatingView.layer.transform = transform;
[self.view addSubview:rotatingView];
```

It is plain simple. But there is absolutely no perspective whatsoever. I expect to see a "skewed" view so that it gives the perspective that it is rotated on the y-axis, but to no avail.

I have even tried setting `zPosition` and the `anchorPoint` but none helps.

I have a feeling that I am just missing just something very simple. How I did it before has slipped out of my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the transform that has perspective with the rotation transform

```
// Define the "transform" variable here
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -500.0;

// assign a new transform to it here
transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(20.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

You should probably be using `CATransform3DRotate` instead:

```
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, DEGREES_RADIANS(20.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: So in general, when should one use `CATransform3DMakeRotation` or `CATransform3DRotate` and do the `x`, `y` and `z` values always needs to be either `0` or `1`, if not how would setting other values other than `0` or `1` effects the transformation (i.e. `3`, `22`)?

Comment: `...MakeRotation` creates a new transform and `...Rotate` rotates another transform. You can think of `...MakeRotation` as being a special case of `...Rotate` in which the identity transform is being rotated.

Comment: You can also create the separate transforms and concatenate them in-order yourself using `CATransform3DConcat`

Comment: The `x, y, z` values are the same in both cases and are used to define the axis of the rotation.

Comment: You can specify something like `0.33, 0.0, 0.66` to rotate around a tilted angle.

Comment: But according to you, `0.33, 0.0, 0.66` would be the same as `1.0, 0.0, 1.0`, correct?

Comment: No, they define the vector that you are rotating around. Like [this image](http://www.real3dtutorials.com/images/img00034.png)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend that you just try and change the axis and you will see better what I'm talking about.

Comment: As an axis only the direction matters, meaning the the vector is normalised. `(0.1, 0, 0)` is the same as `(1, 0, 0)` but `(0.1, 0, 1)` is _not_ the same as `(1, 0, 1)`. Instead it would be the same as `(1, 0, 10)` (but as normalised it would be `(1/11, 0, 10/11)`).

Comment: So you need at least two components to notice any different.

Comment: At this point, this is a different question and I won't continue to elaborate on it in the comments.